# How to calculate when current pay period ends?

Tags: c#

I want to know how to calculate the last date of this pay period?

I know that the pay is bi-weekly and the first period started on 01/09/2012. 
so far here what i have done

```
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    d = Convert.ToDateTime("01/09/2012");

    while (d <= Convert.ToDateTime("01/06/2013")) {

        PayPeriod.Items.Add(new ListItem(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));

        d = d.Date.AddDays(14);
    }
```

And this work perfect, but it work perfect because I have manually put the ending of the current pay period "01/06/2013".

My question is how can I automatically figure out the last date of the current pay period?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with the following logic:

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2012,09,01);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var diff = now.Subtract (startTime);
int daysToEndPeriod = diff.Days % 14;
if (daysToEndPeriod == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("end of pay period");
else
    Console.WriteLine("end of pay period is: " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(14-daysToEndPeriod).Date);
```

This works because you'll always get the Modulo operator returns how many days past the pay period you have left.